# Как отследить изменения в бд?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, json, php

Друзья такой вопрос, мне нужно при появлении нового сообщения воспроизвести звук, мой пхп скрипт успешно посылает джейсоном аяксу массив с результатом выборки а далее я в цикле джейквери вывожу сообщения если в цикл пихать функцию которая воспроизводит звук он естественно воспроизводится сто раз а мне бы всего один разок и то когда новое сообщение пришло. Вопрос собственно такой как отследить изменилось ли что то в базе или считать дивы, а потом проверять не увеличилось ли их колличество? Выборка происходит посредством майэскюэльай ооп подход. Извините что все на русском с сотки сижу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас у сообщений, наверняка есть уникальный цифровой идентификатор. При отправке запроса на наличие последних сообщений, я бы его отправлял, на сервере проверял, появились ли сообщения  с ID больше переданного и если появились, то в ответе посылал флаг наличия нового сообщения, ну и уже анализируя этот флаг проигрывал или не проигрывал музыку.

Answer (score 0):

Да примерно так и есть как пишет aldem67, скрипт проверяет каждые 30 секунд на текущий идентификатор в базе, если он больше того который у него в браузере то данные можно считать изменёнными.
Второй вариант, Вебсокеты, [socket.io](http://socket.io/), сервер оповещает при изменении сервис, который в свою очередь извещает браузер о том что данные изменились.
Примерно так работает Вк стена и мессаги.
Про ПХП и вебсокеты на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/).

Comment: А как быть, если id практически рандомные? не id = {1,2,3,4,5...}, а примерно как номер ролика на тытрубе - id = {x35fjvh228, zj937vksd, ...}?